# (Newbie) How do I set the default location of the map? Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm hoping this is a quick and simple question. The contact page of my website shows a google map and centers on the (previous) location of my business. I wish to change that location to where we moved, but can't find out from where the API is getting the coordinates for the default location.

All I found was the following:
In the head section of my page this:

```html
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false'></script>
```

Under that, this bit of code. I'm not sure what it does or why the coordinates are different for each browser:

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <html class="lt-ie9">
    <div id="ie6-alert" style="width: 100%; text-align:center; background: #232323;">
        <img src="http://beatie6.frontcube.com/images/ie6.jpg" alt="Upgrade IE 6" width="640" height="344" border="0"
             usemap="#Map" longdesc="http://die6.frontcube.com"/>
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <area shape="rect" coords="496,201,604,329"
                  href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx" target="_blank"
                  alt="Download Interent Explorer"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="380,201,488,329" href="http://www.apple.com/safari/download/" target="_blank"
                  alt="Download Apple Safari"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="268,202,376,330" href="http://www.opera.com/download/" target="_blank"
                  alt="Download Opera"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="155,202,263,330" href="http://www.mozilla.com/" target="_blank"
                  alt="Download Firefox"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="35,201,143,329" href="http://www.google.com/chrome" target="_blank"
                  alt="Download Google Chrome"/>
        </map>
    </div>
```

In the CSS, just some basic stuff like the size of the box, etc.

So, what am I missing here? How do I change the default location of the map?

The page in question is here: http://swankypigs.com/index-5.html

Comment: The code in the `<map></map>` tag has nothing to do with the google maps.  This is what HTML uses for image maps.  See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening in your `/js/script.js` file. Just update this with your new location's lat/lng.

```
var myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(33.7238029), parseFloat(-117.267504, 17));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly the info I needed and I was able to set the new location for my map. :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script>
    var map;

    function initialize() {
      var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.933279, 79.849905), //**Change the co-ordinates as you want**
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="googleMap" style="width:1300px;height:550px; margin:auto; padding: 15px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```